# Unable to process a huge trajectory file for MD

Tags: python, pandas, memory

For an MD simulation, I have to read in a big file of coordinates and randomly select few of them and store them.

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
import itertools
import pandas as pd

df = open('/Users/apple/Downloads/traj-3frames.crd','r').readlines()[1:]
df = list(map(lambda x : x.strip().split('  '),df))
image_ends = [i for i,x in enumerate(df) if len(x) < 4]

no_images = 2
images_selected_indices = np.random.choice(len(image_ends),no_images,True)

for index,image in enumerate(images_selected_indices):
image_index = image_ends[image]
if image == 0:
    selected_image = df[0:image_index]
else:
    previous_image_index = image_ends[image-1]
    selected_image = df[previous_image_index + 1:image_index]
flattened_coordinates = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(selected_image))
total_rows = int(len(flattened_coordinates)/3)
coordinates_df = [flattened_coordinates[i*3:(i+1)*3] for i in range(total_rows)]
coordinates_df = pd.DataFrame(coordinates_df,columns = ['x','y','z'])

pickle.dump(coordinates_df,open('image_' + str(index) + '.pkl','wb'))
```

My input file is of 6.7 gb and even computers with 16gb ram are unable to process it, please suggest better ways to manage the memory.

Input File

```
 58.783   3.416  63.966  59.191   2.573  63.767  59.211   3.704  64.773   5.431
 16.078   1.087   6.188  16.647   1.226   4.706  16.534   1.514   2.794  15.157
 13.977   2.273  14.423  14.305   2.369  15.933  14.342  10.048  12.837   4.644
 10.828  13.338   4.404   9.627  13.361   5.325
 66.377  65.275  64.865
 32.355  31.829  32.630  33.434  32.598  31.898  32.073  30.808  32.343  32.476
 31.750  33.717  30.835  32.893  32.578  34.323  33.549  32.603  34.745  32.201
 32.260  33.192  32.780  30.852  34.067  33.743  33.644  34.571  34.408  31.982
```

Comment: Could you post some sample data from the file? It would help as it appears you are loading everything then excluding some (len(x) < 4)

Comment: The sample file is relatively bigger too, but as you can see I am splitting when (len(x) < 4)